# How do I access member functions of concrete class when I'm using Polymorphism and inheritance to declare it as a pointer to the concrete class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, pointer-to-member

Say I have an abstract class.

```
class shape{
public:
shape();
double getWidth();

private:
float m_center;
};
```

and I have a class that inherits from shape.

```
class triangle : public shape{
public:
triangle(vector<double> a, vector<double> b, vector<double> c);
vector<double> getPoints();
void setPoints();
private:
double pointA, pointB, pointC;
};
```

Then say my code is formatted so that when I dealing with shapes I get the shape data in the form of shape pointers. However there are times when I need to access the member functions of the Triangle class, but I only have the shape*

```
int main(){
shape* generalShape = new triangle()     
std::cout << generalShape -> getWidth() << std::endl;

std::vector<double> tempVector = generalShape -> getPoints();    //<- can't do this part.
```

So I can't call member functions from the shape* object so I was just wondering if there is a way to do this or if I have my code structured completely wrong.

Comment: Is it true that every kind of `shape` has a vector of points that it can return? If yes, then you need to include that member function in your base class. If not, then you have to decide what you want to happen when `generalShape` happens to point to a kind of `shape` that doesn't have a vector of points.

Comment: When I see this kind of "need to downcast" pattern, it's a code smell that the object-oriented architecture is not put together correctly.  Perhaps consider putting the logic that wants to access the points of triangle into triangle itself, and have shape have a virtual method named appropriate that does the thing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guess my examples a little contrived, but I intended for the getPoints() function to be dependent on the Triangle class so not every shape has a vector of doubles. I guess another question is can I make a Triangle object from a shape pointer?

Comment: Then it sounds like `getPoints` can't be part of the base class. This leaves you with the decision of how how you want your code to behave when the `shape*` pointer doesn't point to a kind of `shape` that has a `getPoints` member function.

Comment: @HenryKeskitalo -- Your code is where the `if it's this object, do this, if it's another object type, do that, if it's something else, do something else` coding that polymorphism tries to avoid is starting to happen.  Ask yourself *why* at that point in the general shape code logic, you need to know that you're dealing with triangles.

Comment: If the getPoints function doesn't apply to certain shapes or is different for some shapes. Do you think it is wise to make a pure virtual function in the base class and have an implementation for the triangles, and maybe return null for other shapes that it doesn't apply to?

Comment: @HenryKeskitalo Probably not. This is likely the result of a design error. You shouldn't usually find yourself in a context where you have a `shape*` pointer while you actually want a pointer to a more derived type. You could use `dynamic_cast` to get back a `triangle*` from the `shape*` (you'd need to make `shape` polymorphic first) but that is usually indicative of a design error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it doesn't make sense to use a virtual function in the base class, you can achieve this doing a dynamic_cast. There does need to be at least one virtual function in base class.

```
triangle* newPtr = dynamic_cast<triangle*>(generalShape);
```

One should understand the costs and advantages of this approach (run-time polymorphism); and consider whether it is more efficient to redesign the class.